# How can I edit command-line args in shortcuts generated by InstallShield?

Tags: command-line-arguments, shortcut, installshield-le

Sometimes when an installer installs a program, and creates shortcuts, for some reason they aren't "normal" shortcuts. They have the Target textbox and Open File Location button greyed out, like such:

[image]

I'm using InstallShield 2011 LE (Limited Edition) for Visual Studio 2010. It works as advertised, but I don't see any options to change the way it creates shortcuts.  The program I'm installing would greatly benefit from adding command line arguments to that Target textbox.  If I go find the executable in Program Files, and Send To -> Desktop (create shortcut), I (and my users) can modify that one, no problem. I don't want to have to make them go through this step, though.

How are shortcuts placed by an installer different from "normal" shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

In InstallShield, set the Advertise property to "no".

Comment: Where is the Advertise property?  I can't find it.

Comment: I don't have Limited Edition installed so maybe it doesn't expose it. Find where you create the shortcut and look for a property grid.  See if it mentions a property with the worse Advertise it in.   Otherwise see if you can define the property DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS and set it to 1.  See the following for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368297(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, and DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS definitely sounds like what I'm after, but I'm unsure where I would be defining this property.  This page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368760(v=vs.85).aspx talks about Getting and Setting properties, but I'm still lost.  All I have to work with is InstallShield 2011 LE for VS 2010.